# Parameter value [...] did not match expected type java.util.Date

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-data-jpa

The following method fails eventhough the type of the `date` field is `LocalDate`:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM #{#entityName} e WHERE date = :date")
List<DTO> findAllByDate(LocalDate date);
```

Exception:

```
Parameter value [2014-08-23] did not match expected type java.util.Date
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addressing the `date` field with the table alias fixes the problem: (Notice the `e.`)

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM #{#entityName} e WHERE e.date = :date")
```